# clearcase-settings file.xml for maven

Tags: maven-2, maven, clearcase

I am using Maven for integration with Clearcase. Documents says use clearcase-settings.xml, from where can i get clearcase-settings.xml? do i need to replace settings.xml from conf folder to clearcase-settings.xml?.
if yes, do i need to delete settings.xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a different file. You can place it in `${maven.home}/conf` or `${user.home}/.scm`

See http://maven.apache.org/scm/clearcase.html#ClearCase_settings_file

Comment: only those tags are sufficient? ie <useVWSParameter>, <clearcaseType>, <viewstore>. anything else do i need to specify?.           what is the difference in User home and Maven home? I need to integrate Maven with UCM clearcase with dynamic view type. So which one should I go? ie user.home or maven.home?

Answer (score 1):

> only those tags are sufficient?

`<useVWSParameter>`, `<clearcaseType>`, `<viewstore>` are the only tags managed by the maven Clearcase plugin.

> what is the difference in User home and Maven home?

Those are the two location where the maven ClearCase plugin will look for additional settings.

> I need to integrate Maven with UCM clearcase with dynamic view type

Note that the ClearCase SCM provider uses snapshot views only.

Comment: ClearCase SCM provider uses snapshot views only?....... can you clarify more on this? Since i am using dynamic view, cant i integrate Maven for dynamic view?

Comment: @user706295: As mentioned in http://maven.apache.org/scm/clearcase.html#ClearCase_dynamic_views, you could use dynamic view by using the SCM local file system provider instead (http://maven.apache.org/scm/local.html), but I don't have much experience with this option.